# How does positive feedback makes Schmitt trigger faster than a comparator?

Tags: schmitt-trigger

Besides eliminating noise, one of the advantage of Schmitt trigger is given as speed.

And what I saw that the reason of this is the positive feedback used by Schmitt trigger.

Does that mean Schmitt trigger responses input faster so it makes the input pulse's rising edge sharper comparing to a comparator? And how is positive feedback making things faster? How does it cause the output's rise time to be shorter comparing to a comparator?

(Question is about comparing a comparator and s Schimtt trigger's speed and assuming input pulse has no noise. How Schmitt trigger resulting faster rising edges...)

Comment: Read references given [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/673552).

Comment: I will try but at least is my assumption correct? Does  Schmitt trigger make the input's rising edge sharper comparing to a comparator? Or sharpening rising edge is irrelevant to being Schmitt trigger or comparator?

Comment: Or am I wrong: The response time of both a Schmitt trigger and a comparator largely depends on their design and the specific components used. Neither inherently responds faster than the other???

Comment: A schmitt trigger has several purposes. But one of them is to sharpen one or both output edges with respect to input edges. The word 'comparator' is abused and may just be an opamp that compares two voltages but without positive feedback. But if it does use positive feedback, then it's a Schmitt trigger in all likelihood.

Comment: It somewhat depends on technology. But in all cases if the input switch is driven by a larger voltage differential charge carriers will be transferred more rapidly than otherwise.  At turn on the Schmitt trigger output voltage is partially transferred to the input, increasing delta-Vin at any given moment.  At turn off the delta V is decreased so cutoff is reached faster ((but, drive current is lower sooner so ... :-) ))

Comment: @RussellMcMahon But if the input has too short rise time, is there a possibility that the input slew rate of the Schmitt trigger might not detect the rising edge of the input or distort the signal?

Comment: re " ... short rise time ... " -->
No. Schmitt triggers are level triggered. A "too fast" input rise time just means tht they will rspond as fast as they are able. It's up to the designer to decide whether that is fast enough for the application. Where short rise times faster than device switching speed are encountered factor Schmitt triggers are less liable to be needed. ST is usually used for excessively slow and/or noisy input changes.

Answer (score 1):

A Schmitt trigger also is a comparator. The reference input is internal, but not in the same way as an comparator.

The rise and fall times are determined by the speed of the internal transistors in both the Schmitt trigger and the comparator.

Hysteresis occurs when the reference is driven lower while the input is driven higher (and vice versa). This accomplishes two benefits:

1. "Chattering" on the output is eliminated for noisy inputs up to a point. So this better defines the switching threshold.
2. It allows the internal transistors to operate at their fastest switching speed.

Hysteresis is the main difference between an op-amp operated in open-loop as a comparator and a properly designed comparator with hysteresis. An op-amp can be operated as a comparator by using positive feedback, but care must be taken to avoid unwanted oscillations or instability.