# How do I switch on an LED strip when the control signal is pulled low?

Tags: mosfet, p-channel

So I'm basically trying to take a control signal from one device (5 V), and use it to control a 12 V LED strip (1 A or more).

The control device is an electronic dance pad (StepManiaX Stage,or Dance Dance Revolution if that helps). I have checked how the signal is output on the electronics and it seems that the signal wire is constantly at 5 V, but when the panel is stepped on it gets pull down to 0 V (ground). What I want, is to light up the LED strips when that signal is pulled to 0 V which is typically the opposite for when you use a MOSFET as a switch.

I have previously used MOSFETs as switches to drive LED strips, but it's always been a high control signal to turn them on. I have tried looking up the answers to this, but I must admit I have become somewhat overwhelmed with something I thought would have a fairly simple solution.

My gut tells me I possibly want to use P-channel instead of N-channel, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it.

Ideally I also don't want to affect the control signal in any significant way as I am essentially splitting it so it still goes to where it was originally headed, and also to my LED strip circuit, so ideally the solution doesn't introduce any thing weird with the original signal.

I mocked up a simple circuit diagram of what I *think* it would essentially look like.

[image: theoretical circuit]

Comment: I cannot say for certain (you should use a scope on that signal to see what it really looks like) but you probably will want to use a [Schmitt trigger](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/673552/330261) to precondition the transition to 0 V before using it with the rest of the circuitry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple inverter should work. For Bjt use some signal transistor like 3904. 100k resistor certainly do not affect the signal source.

[image]